# Quando usar "rsize_t" ao invés de "size_t"?

Tags: c, tipagem

Qual é a diferença entre `rsize_t` e `size_t`, sendo que procurando no rascunho eu encontrei no item **K.3.6 General utilities** :

> rsize_t
>  
>   which is the type size_t;

que significa que são do mesmo tipo, mas não encontrei descrição da diferença, que ao que parece é na utilização.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basicamente é uma questão semântica, você  passa a ideia melhor do que está fazendo. Assim diz que está escolhendo um tamanho dentro de uma determinada faixa. De fato parece que consideram isso inútil e há uma proposta que seja retirado da especificação já que os compiladores resolveram não adotá-lo, então nem perca tempo com isso.

Até existe utilidade quando a semântica diferente faz mais sentido, e de uma certa forma o `size_t` pode ser substituído por um `int` (não em todas situações), e de fato em exercícios e códigos ingênuos vemos isso o tempo todo, mas não é correto, apenas funciona (na maioria dos casos). Este tipo for criado para lidar com um tamanho na memória e não um número qualquer.

Se os programadores observassem mais a semântica das coisas as aplicações seriam bem melhores em todos os sentidos, inclusive ser melhor de manutenção.